# MySQL model and database synchronization ERROR

Tags: mysql

I have created my tables inside a ER model, and when I try to synchronize the model with the server I am presented with an Error Log that I cant figure out. Just before this screen is shown only 2 out of the 15 tables sources are found the rest say "Red arrow --> N/A"

p.s I have only done this through an ER model I have not put any SQL in manually.

here is the log i am being presented with.

> Executing SQL script in server
>
> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') REFERENCES `StudentRetentionSystemdb`.`module` () ON DELETE NO ACTION' at line 8

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `StudentRetentionSystemdb`.`tutor` (   
  `PersonID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,    
  `moduleLeader` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,    
  `departmentCode` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonID`) ,    
  INDEX `departmentCode_idx` (`departmentCode` ASC) ,    
  CONSTRAINT `moduleLeader` FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `StudentRetentionSystemdb`.`module` () 
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,    
  CONSTRAINT `departmentCode` FOREIGN KEY (`departmentCode` )    
    REFERENCES `StudentRetentionSystemdb`.`department` (`departmentCode` )   
      ON DELETE NO ACTION  
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `CREATE TABLE` statement somewhere on the declaration on `INDEX`. You should remove `ASC` from the index part.

```
INDEX `departmentCode_idx` (`departmentCode`)
```

The second problem that will arise is that you have no key define on the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint,

```
CONSTRAINT `moduleLeader` FOREIGN KEY (moduleLeader)           -- add column name
    REFERENCES `StudentRetentionSystemdb`.`module` (columnName)-- add column name
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```